# How to listen for incoming websocket messages from multiple places using Tornado?

Tags: python, python-3.x, websocket, tornado

Let's say I have an infinite `while` loop that awaits the `read_message()` method of a WebSocket Tornado client connection. Then, I externally trigger a function that sends a message and should get an immediate response.
Since everything is asynchronous, I would assume that when that external call takes place, the execution goes over to it. But when I try to listen for a response inside that call, it throws an `AssertionError` stating that `self.read_future` is not `None`, when it should be.

Here are the methods of the client application. A little earlier, it connects to a server and places the connection in the `self.conn` variable:

```
async def loop(self):
    while True:
        print(await self.conn.read_message())

async def ext_call(self):
    self.conn.write_message('Hello, World!')
    response = await self.conn.read_message()  # This line fails
```

Why can't I listen for messages in two separate places?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're asking for is ambiguous - which messages would go to which place? It looks like you probably mean for the next message to arrive after you send "Hello world" to be handled in `ext_call`, and all others to be printed in `loop`. But how could the system know that? Consider that the "Hello world" message could be sent to the client *and the response received* before the python interpreter has executed the `read_message` call in `ext_call`, so it would be routed to the waiting `read_message` in `loop`.

In general, you want to use one of these patterns but not both at the same time. If you always have matched request/response pairs of messages, you can read after you send as in `ext_call`. But if you may have messages that are not a part of request/response pairs, you need *one* loop that reads all the messages and decides what to do with them (perhaps splitting them up by type and emitting them on one or more queues using the `tornado.queues` module).

Comment: Is there any difference between Python's `queue.Queue` and `tornado.queues.Queue`?

Comment: Yes - `queue.Queue` has a synchronous interface and is thread-safe; `tornado.queues.Queue` has an asynchronous interface and is not thread-safe. Tornado applications should use the asynchronous `tornado.queues.Queue`, unless you need to communicate with a non-Tornado thread (in which case `queue.Queue` is sometimes appropriate, but you must only use the `_nowait` methods from the Tornado thread).